# Genymotion stuck on android boot screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I'm new to Genymotion because I used android phones to test my apps but now I have to test my app on tablets and I don't own one.

The Genymotion seems to work fine but the emulator doesn't seem to bootup and is stuck on android boot screen. I've waited for more than an hour but the result is same. I tried researching on the internet but can't find an answer. I'm using genymotion 2.8.0 and my machine has an AMD A4 processor.

[Android boot loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4da8.png)

I also tried running through VirtualBox directly but it doesn't seem to work either.
Please help me out.

Comment: boot can stuck when You use VPN, be sure emulator has connection to network